# Chrome debugger skips inline JavaScript code on first click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, inline-code

When using the `Mouse` `click` option under the `sources` of the `Event Listener Breakpoints` option on the right, the debugger skips the following function code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test()
            {
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="return test();" value="test">
    </body>
</html>
```

**The problem is not that it doesn't run. It's that I can't debug it until I push the `input` button twice to be able to `step into (F11)` the function.**

Otherwise I'm not able to debug what's inside the code. It's pretty frustrating because it happens **every** time I refresh the page. Is this a bug or is it meant to be like this?

I'm on: Chrome Ubuntu Version 40.0.2214.93 (64-bit)

P.S. For those that asked/will ask,

I'm working on maintaining a legacy application and unfortunately, it has many inline functions. There's no point in taking the time of putting all these into files when my company is building new software to replace it. Since resources are spent building out the new code, I'll have to do minor debugging of the legacy application this way.

Comment: try putting a console.log("hello"); before the return true; in your function.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using inline event handlers in the first place?

Comment: My guess would be that since you're using an onclick attribute, you're not actually binding the function as the handler to the event. Instead, your binding an anonymous function that executes the function.

Comment: This may be weird, but try `onclick="console.log(test())"`. Should print `true` in your console.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem, and I notice that on the first click, the Call Stack says `(anonymous function)` and never enters `test`, while any click after that has the expected Call Stack of `onclick`, followed by `test` on top of `onclick`. Also curious is that the Scope of `(anonymous function)` is Global-only, rather than the usual `with` block scopes and local scope (including a `this` of the clicked input element). You can see this by setting a Watch Expression of `this==window` -- the first time it is `true` and all other times it is sometimes `false`.

Comment: Seems to run http://jsfiddle.net/ccyzaegm/1/

Comment: @Huangism The problem isn't that it doesn't run, is that I'm not able to debug it on the first click.

Comment: @Tek yes I get it now, if your debugger/firebug is not open when your page load then it won't work.

Comment: @Huangism Having debugger open when the page loads doesn't work either. You would expect for it to work on the first click.

Comment: @Tek I am sure someone will have a good answer for you

Comment: @KevinB has the right idea. It appears that on first time, an anonymous function binds the inline listener, and *then* the listener runs. (On future clicks, the function runs immediately.) On the first click, it seems the binding function runs in response to the click, while the inline `onclick` function does *not* run in response to the click, from the viewpoint of the debugger. (The `onclick` does run, but it runs at the request of this anonymous first-time function, not in response to the click, apparently.)

Comment: Observe the above situation by adding a `debugger;` statement to the beginning of your `onclick`. You see`(anonymous function)` run first, in response to the initial click, and *then* the `onclick` listener runs, because of the `debugger;` statement. If you omit the `debugger;` statement, you only see `(anonymous function)` run, and the `onclick` function does not get passed over by the debugger.

Comment: Just tested in Chrome Canary - it works for the first call, however you have to click "Step into" five times to get to the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me, though I am using v38. As a workaround try adding the debugger statement into the handler (while you are debugging)

```
function test(){
    debbugger;
    return true;
}
```